# Pure HTML/CSS to create triangle pointer under button

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a div that looks like this:

[image]

I need to edit the HTML/CSS so that it displays like this with a small triangle underneath. Ideally, I would like to do this using purely HTML and CSS, no image files. According to [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/st) it can be done.

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><div class="triangle"></div>Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="users/index.html"><div class="triangle"></div>Manage Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="tickets/index.html"><div class="triangle"></div>Manage Tickets</a></li>
    <li><a href="reports/index.html"><div class="triangle"></div>Reports</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#nav li a {
    color: #0b70cc;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 5px;
}

#nav li.active a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#nav li.active {
    background-color: #0b70cc;
    color: white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpeKy/)

If anyone can help me do this I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Generate your own div with an arrow at http://cssarrowplease.com/

You can configure it like you want and become a clean CSS

---

How it works:
Lets' create a very simple triangle with this technique:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.container:after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

The important thing is `height: 0;` & `width: 0` of the pseudo-element where we apply the border. So you can imagine an element of no size. And this is the origin of the border. So each side of the border is a triangle (try colorize each side in a different color to understand it).
So to create the "single triangle" effect, just apply a transparent color to the border and colorize the triangle you want to display.

---

**Alternative: [CSS Clip-Path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)**

You can create a rectangle now very easy with the new `clip-path` with CSS. 
Just watch out for the browser-support. As usual, IE & sadly Edge both won't support it as well as Opera Mini: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Quick Example:

```css
.new_way {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #88b7d5;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new_way::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  background: #88b7d5;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  /* The points are: (left top: x y, right top: x y, center bottom: x y) */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="new_way">
  Clip Path
</div>
```

So now you only need 1 line. Nice, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, a great site. I've also used it but completely forgot about it :)

Comment: YOu'll need to add a high z-index to the arrow if its to appear over something else (in it was on the top li of a vertical ul).

Comment: Great site but I'd really like to know how the div ends up with an arrow. Is it because of the negative/positive margins? What forms the arrow shape?

Comment: @gideon: added the explanation. feel free to ask again if I something is unclear.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Got it once I played with it on jsfiddle.

Comment: @gideon: I just edited the answer to add the new `clip-path`. It's much much easier with this. Have a look

Comment: But we can't add border or shadow in clip-path element.

Answer (score 9):

This is called "callout".

Here are some examples:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/bv45bh6p (some examples)

http://mrcoles.com/blog/callout-box-css-border-triangles-cross-browser/ (with explanation of how it works)