# Center Triangle at Bottom of Div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to have a triangle/arrow at the bottom of my hero but it is not responsive and doesn't work on mobile very well as the triangle floats off to the right and is not absolutely centered anymore.

How could I keep the triangle positioned in the absolute center at the bottom of the div at all times?

Example code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SxKr5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="hero"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {     
    position:relative;
    background-color:#e15915;
    height:320px !important;
    width:100% !important;


}


.hero:after,
.hero:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: 70%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

Comment: @PKHunter check my answer, I put the IE filter for Microsoft too.

Comment: Simply use `left: calc(50% - 50px)`. You can remove the negative left margin.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Can't you just set `left` to `50%` and then have `margin-left` set to `-25px` to account for it's width: http://jsfiddle.net/9AbYc/

```
.hero:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

or if you needed a variable width you could use: http://jsfiddle.net/9AbYc/1/

```
.hero:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use following css to make an element middle aligned styled with `position: absolute`:

```
.element {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

With CSS having only `left: 50%` we will have following effect:

[image: Image with left: 50% property only]

While combining `left: 50%` with `transform: translate(-50%)` we will have following:

[image: Image with transform: translate(-50%) as well]

```css
.hero {  
  background-color: #e15915;
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
}


.hero:after {
  border-right: solid 50px transparent;
  border-left: solid 50px transparent;
  border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">

</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Worked on IE11 :)

Comment: The position: absolute requirement makes it a bit difficult for things like tooltips in most frameworks. But thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 7):

Check this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/SxKr5/3/**

```
.hero1
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #e15915;
}

.hero2
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: auto;
    border-width: 90px 58px 0 58px;
    border-color: #e15915 transparent transparent transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #e15915 #000000 #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a CSS "calc" to get the same effect instead of using the negative margin or transform properties (in case you want to use those properties for anything else).

```
.hero:after,
.hero:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 98.1%;
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 50px #e15915;
    border-left: solid 50px transparent;
    border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but you could also consider using clip-path, as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208889/23341.