# HTML/CSS Create Div with Arrow Bottom

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create the following object as a DIV in HTML/CSS.

[image]

I've created the following jsfiddle to test with:
http://jsfiddle.net/fz4f4xjv/2/

below is code I have but I'm not sure how to create the arrow on the bottom:

```
<div id="menuSelected"></div>
#menuSelected {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #368EC5;
}
```

thankyou :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there are many similar questions under the CSS-Shapes tag mate.

Comment: this question should help too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div

Comment: you can create a :after tag and style a tringle there.
fe
     #menuSelected {
        width: 250px;
        height: 35px;
        background-color: #368EC5;
         position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #menuSelected:after,
    #menuSelected::after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -40%;
        content: '';
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: solid 10px #368EC5;
        border-left: solid 10px transparent;
        border-right: solid 10px transparent;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a span with the absolute position to that div.

```
<div class="menuSelected"><span></span></div>

#menuSelected {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #368EC5;
}
span {
    border-top: 10px solid #368EC5;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz4f4xjv/7/).