# How to make square in Twitter Bootstrap around the item?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, ionic-framework

I am trying to make some web page as show in image .I am able to make almost 90%.But I have one issue

- how to make square as shown in image (a square which have triangle in bottom.I know we can make square using border .but how to make triangle in that bottom triangle
- how to make contend scrollable mean my contend it not scrolling I already use **overflow:auto and scroll**

)

```
.bg {
    background: #597A4D!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}
.nav_bar {
    background: #597A4D!important;
    border-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0px!important;
    border-radius: 0px!important;

}
.display_menu li a{
    font-size: 1.2em!important;
    color: #ffffff!important;
}

ul.display_menu li:last-child{
    background:#3C86D7;
}

.rowClass {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 3%;

}
.rowClass >div {
    padding: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
.text_row div{
    display: block;
    border: 1px ;
    padding: auto;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 3%;

}

.rowClass span {
    display: block!important;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.logo_image{
  width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.email_div label {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.email_div{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
.email_div  label {

}
.email_div input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #3C86D7;
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
}
.email_div button {
    display: inline;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow: auto!important;
    overflow: scroll!important;
}
```

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G8mp53rQlF562hEkgmgT?p=preview

[image]

Comment: I downloaded plunk and when I opened in my browser it scrolling may  be you facing browser issue

Comment: no ...please check check again but how to make rectangle.as show in image]

Comment: can use border property for normal rectangle

Comment: @ShubhamPatel Are you reading the question? The OP directly stated they know how to make a rectangle around the item, they want to know how to make the triangle on the bottom.

Comment: I know the how to make rectangle but there is one triangle in bottom I need that how tot make this

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek do you know how to make this ? or shubham can could you please help me making this

Comment: or use a image but i recommend use SVG instead a image

Comment: SVG is best option because it scale according to window size

Comment: I highly do not recommend using an image or the HTML 5 Canvas, they are not for things like this, it's what CSS is for. Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div), or you may want to use [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Comment: Ok I will look into this answer ..!! but why it is not scrolling

Comment: @Shruti It's because you need to add your scrolling overflow to `ion-view` other than your wrapper. That will fix your scrolling problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it is not correct because when i added this it also scroll my header also.i need header remain fixed and contend will scroll

Comment: did you define a height for wrapper class because when I defined it start working

Comment: where I don't see on plunk or on above code. you defined only for logo image as in above code please recheck

Comment: I've just added  this height:200px before overflow

Answer (score 1):

just do this

```
.wrapper{
    overflow: auto!important;
    overflow: scroll!important
    height: 200px;
}
```

or desired height instead of

```
.wrapper{
    overflow: auto!important;
    overflow: scroll!important;
}
```

it will start scrolling because it will only scroll if data is overflowing

and for shape this [article](http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/bootstrap-popover#) may help but you don't need to use any thing just use bootstrap tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the overflowing

```
.wrapper{
overflow: auto!important;
overflow: scroll!important
height: 250px;
```

}

to get an idea to make those box with shapes, 
See this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dd9od35s/)**