# CSS triangle under table row element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add "CSS Triangle" under the first table row at the center, like the next picture:

[image]

I tried to do it with ::after the first row as shown in previous examples but the positioning wasn't correct.

Here is the table without the triangle

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

td.content {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <td> # </td>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="content"> content </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just so you know, don't use `<tr class="header">` - it has no usability functionality. Use `<thead><tr><th>Header content</th></tr></thead>` instead. It actually has semantic meaning.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do the after on the td element rather than the row. Here's one method, which is demonstrated below.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

td.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.red-triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 25px red;
  border-left: solid 25px transparent;
  border-right: solid 25px transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <td> # </td>
        <td class="red-triangle"> 1 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="content"> content </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To horizontally centre the triangle use `left: calc(50% - 25px);`. Also, the td's need `position: relative;` set, and the triangle should have `top: 100%;`