# Border around a div with a triangle point at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to achieve this border in CSS? I've got one DIV with list of bullet points and I need to wrap it in a border like the image.

[image]

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: Refer this answer in this Stackoverflow Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div

Comment: Please check it my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create one element with border except `border-bottom` and then use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to add triangle border at bottom.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
div:after, div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 101px 0 101px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  position: absolute;
}
div:after {
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5euk3wcn/)

Basically add this css to a div:

```
#base {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#base:after {
  border-bottom: 35px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  width: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 .down-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: darkcyan;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.down-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid darkcyan;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9AbYc/1342/)

Comment: This is same as another answer in stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div

Comment: please check it my demo @Nayana_Das

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the box:

```css
.box {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.box:after {
    border-top: 35px solid #fff;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    width: 0;
}
.box:before {
    border-top: 35px solid #000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

I hope it helps