# Center Triangle at Bottom of Div with box-shadow

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a div with a smooth box-shadow which has a triangle created using the "border trick" (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div#) stackoverflow question). I want to have the box-shadow on the triangle as well. Since it is made with borders this is probably impossible, but do you know any alternative way / relatively elegant workaround for this problem?

The snippet below is the current version of my code, without the triangle shadow.

```css
.hero {
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px green;
}

.hero:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 50px red;
  border-left: solid 50px transparent;
  border-right: solid 50px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

[Picture of the Layout right now, with the missing shadow around the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdya7.png)

Comment: https://codepen.io/ryanmcnz/pen/JDLhu

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. However, when I resize the window, the box-shadow of the big div sometimes draws a line through the triangle, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Not sure if that is only caused by the Chrome f12 "responsive" tool, as this doesn't happen when I resize the window manually

Answer (score 2):

You could try a *"transform rotate"* trick, as demonstrated in the code snippet below.

```css
.hero {
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    height: 320px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px green;
}

.hero:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px green;
}

.hero-clip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: inherit;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="hero-clip"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a kludgey workaround, but my approach would be to overlap a square div rotated 45 degrees, as I did in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/needsmorejson/wgxp1tcp/

HTML:

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="sidekick">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero {
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 320px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px green;
}
.sidekick{
  width:71px !important;
  height:71px !important;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 333px;
  left: 50%;
  padding-top: -25px !important;
  margin-top -25px !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: red;
  border-top: solid 0px transparent;
  border-right: solid 0px transparent;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 4px green;
}
```

It is worth noting however, that my "triangle" is not quite centered properly.