# Style Bottom Center Point of Div as Triangle

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.buck-knives-inner-nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.buck-knives-inner-nav-tab {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.buck-knives-inner-nav-tab:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #707070;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0B0E55;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/*
.active::after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 20px solid #0B0E55;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="buck-knives-inner-nav">
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab active">
      Hold Old is My Knife?
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Knife Sharpening
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Safety Tips
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Knife Care
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Choosing the Right Knife
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Buck's Forever Warranty
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering - is it possible to style the `active` tab differently so that it points downward at the bottom center, like I have it in the following mockup?

[image]

I tried to implement the downward-facing triangle effect that's used in this article:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

adding it as an `::after` to the `active` tab - so why didn't that have any effect?

```
.active::after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 20px solid #0B0E55;
}
```

Also tried something similar - what I found here: [Center Triangle at Bottom of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719048/center-triangle-at-bottom-of-div)

All other ideas / suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You need to define content in a pseudo element, and to think about how to position it properly in relation to its element.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the position on the `after` element.

I've added a `position: relative;` on the `buck-knives-inner-nav-tab` and some more positioning on the after:

```css
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
```

```css
.buck-knives-inner-nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.buck-knives-inner-nav-tab {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.buck-knives-inner-nav-tab:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #707070;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0B0E55;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.buck-knives-inner-nav-tab.active:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 20px solid #0B0E55;
  
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="buck-knives-inner-nav">
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab active">
      Hold Old is My Knife?
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Knife Sharpening
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Safety Tips
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Knife Care
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab active">
      Choosing the Right Knife
  </div>
  <div class="buck-knives-inner-nav-tab">
      Buck's Forever Warranty
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm going for. Would you mind taking a look at this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/um0of512/ I'm wondering why the bottom left and bottom right sides do not seem to start going down at an angle right away? Instead they seem to go straight across for about 5 - 10 pixels and then change into the angle I'm looking for. Any way to start the angle directly from the corner point? [example](https://i.imgur.com/hettToj.png)