# Responsive bootstrap button with down arrow

Tags: css, button, responsive

Can someone tell if it s possible to create this kind of button with bootstrap butttons? Or can it be done only with css ? I need it to be responsive.

[image: responsive button]

Comment: If you are interested in the "triangle" pointer effect at the bottom of the button, bootstrap probably doesn't provide that (you can use CSS though). The responsive button is perfectly doable with just bootstrap.

Comment: So if i make it with only CSS it wouldn t be responsive?

Comment: It would, if you do it correctly of course. You see, bootstrap is just a superset of a plain CSS. Everything that bootstrap does is doable with plain CSS. Not everything you can do with plain CSS is also doable with just bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could provide a picture or example of what you are after that would be helpful. Bootstrap is built to be responsive so Bootstrap buttons are responsive straight out of the box.

Go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups for a comprehensive list of Bootstrap buttons and how to use them.

Here are examples of arrows that can be used in buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
</button>
```

[image]

and here's a dropdown menu with a down arrow.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Show us a picture and try to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Have a look at this code. Its a callout button. <http://cssdeck.com/labs/bv45bh6p>

Comment: And some more useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208839/pure-html-css-to-create-triangle-pointer-under-button